# IE fails to load the css on the first time load

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position

Well, I have a problem in with IE Compability View and the loading IE7 style sheet when the View is enabled.

I've added the style sheet's to every explorer (can't target IE10). And it seems to work ok when testing in IE10 F12 Developer's tools.

Here is the [Link](http://www.ebay.es/itm/Funda-Gel-PROTECTOR-CARGADOR-COCHE-HUAWEI-ASCEND-G300-U8818-U8815-/200818507423?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_186&hash=item2ec1b73e9f#ht_1948wt_1163)

But... When I load the page (listing) on first run of explorer I get this result [image: IE Errror]
In this case I test it on IE mode, but the same happens with Compability mode.

The Funny thing is, if I hit refresh, then the right stylesheet load's and the problem is gone.

Can it be because of this line I have in the code:

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/><![endif]-->
```

[image]

I put it in if statement because it affected my default style sheet in Chrome.

Comment: I deleted the X-UA-Comatible and still the problem remains.

Comment: Is the CSS references in the <HEAD>?
(the link given above sends me to ebay, not this page)

Comment: Well, yes, because this is the ebay template

Comment: Sorry, forgot to scroll.. When I am right, there is no <head> section in the HTML. The <link rel...> used to load the CSS must (according to HTML standards) be placed within a <head>. Give it a try if possible in the CMS by any chance...

Comment: I gave up devoloping web sites for IE long time ago. I think if we were remove IE in the internet media, all the problems would be solved. :)

Comment: well, in Spain the IE usage is still 50%, so I'm forced to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate the CSS import, but the second one but it inside

```
      <!--[if IE]>   here    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

try  `content="chrome=1"`

You should also look into something called chrome frame,

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started

...

I really think it's probably because you have a white space before the DOCTYPE, or if you are loading it using javascript, make sure you don't have `console.log()` that causes errors, (the later is only if loaded the css file through javascript.

I hope this helps or gives you a direction where to go from there.